# Make the CTRL and Super/CMD keys behave like on OS X

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, mac

I am a longtime OS X user who is using Ubuntu at work. While I like Ubuntu very much, something that I really miss is the behavior of the CTRL & CMD (i.e. Super) keys on OS X:

- CMD/Super is used for most GUI shortcuts, such as copy/pasting, closing windows, ...
- CTRL is mainly used for entering control keys in the terminal, i.e. CTRL+C generates a SIGINT.

While working in a terminal I can still use the same shortcuts for copying and pasting. I find this immensely practical. On Ubuntu I have to use the mouse and the contextual menu.

Is there any way I can make these keys behave like on OS X?

Comment: To copy/paste in a terminal, use Ctrl+Shift+C/V/X. These combinations are fixed, you can't change them. You may give KDE a try, where the Super key is a modifier key.

Comment: @the_Seppi it really answers my question actually. If you care to add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I've done it on my MAC book running Kubuntu :

1. **Use xmodmap to swap command key and ctrl key globally.**
   a) Put the following in a file ~/.Xmodmap

   ```
   clear control  
   clear mod4  

   keycode 105 =  
   keycode 206 =  

   keycode 133 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L  
   keycode 134 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R  
   keycode 37 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L  

   add control = Control_L  
   add control = Control_R  
   add mod4 = Super_L
   ```

   b) Run the following command :

   ```
   $ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```

   This will make all your application use Command + .. instead of ctrl + .. **except terminal**
   Remember, your command key is now ctrl key

**2. Modify shortcut keys for Terminal**

a) In terminal application, go to "Configure Shortcuts"
b) Change the shortcuts for the following :

- Cut - To 'Command + c '
- Paste - To 'Command + v '
- Interrupt - To 'Ctrl + c '
- New Tab - To ' Command + t'
- Close Tab - To 'Command + w'
- Any other key your are particular about ..

**3. Disable Meta key from invoking the app launcher**  [ kubuntu only ]

Add the following to ~/.config/kwinrc

```
[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]  
Meta=
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually CAN use the Cut/Copy/Paste-Hotkeys in a terminal: You just have to additionally use the Shift key:

Copy: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Paste: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Cut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

---

Some command editing shortcuts:

Delete one word: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Move cusrsor one word left/right: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

---

If you want to use the Super key as a modifier, there is no possibility to do so in GTK-based desktop environments. If this is a important feature for you, you could give KDE a try.