# How to make the keyboard shortcuts like macOS on Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, software-recommendation, macosx

I've seen plenty of questions regarding this, but they all seem to do a *remap* of the keys, instead of an actual macOS behavior.

My main use case would be to "split" the shortcuts: for example I would like to have <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy text, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to send a SIGINT to the current program.

In this case, a simple remap or swap of <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> would not work.

I find the behavior of the mac to be very practical, because all the most common shortcuts use <kbd>Super</kbd>, and the famous *copy* shortcut doesn't overlap the famous *SIGINT* shortcut.

Most terminal apps react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-* shortcuts, and they mostly overlap with "standard" shortcuts. In GNOME Terminal, we have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy text, whereas in other applications like Firefox, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used. This is quite cumbersome and inconsistent compared to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Would like to point to another answer on askubuntu : https://askubuntu.com/questions/521202/make-the-ctrl-and-super-cmd-keys-behave-like-on-os-x/1009537#1009537

Answer (score 7):

**Ubuntu 20.04, June 2020**

After spending an insane amount of time trying to figure out how to get MacOS-like shortcuts working on Ubuntu, I've found [kinto](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto). Just follow the [instructions](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto#how-to-install-linux), it worked perfectly on 20.04 for me using an Apple aluminum keyboard. CMD-C/V copies & pastes everywhere and CTRL-C etc. work in the terminal.

Comment: Doesn't work on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve using xmodmap commands:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
keysym Super_L = Control_L
add Control = Control_L
```

Save the above lines as `super_as_ctrl.xmodmap`. Test by executing

```
xmodmap super_as_ctrl.xmodmap
```

To make the change permanent (surviving re-login/reboot) just rename the file to `.Xmodmap` in your home folder.

(Tested on Ubuntu 14.x)

PS: You could also make use of other windows button. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: That makes Ctrl-C and Super-C both send `^C` to the shell. I expected one of these to behave like copy. Tested on elementary OS

Answer (score -1):

To create new shortcut and delete old ones, Simply go to **system settings >> keyboard >> shortcuts**. There you can see all the shortcuts, edit it, delete it and create new ones.

Answer (score -1):

The following lives in my `$HOME/.uxSwapCapsLock-and-Ctrl`. It effectively swaps the functionality of the CapsLock and Ctrl keys for any shell in use on any Linux system whenever I log in, and initiate an interactive session within a shell, on a given system. I'm sure you can learn about the pertinent key name that you are trying to modify, and are referred to by xmodmap, in order to get the functionality you want. This code gets initiated every time I login and have an interactive session via .profile, but it lives in a .ps1 file for this purpose.

```bsh
#!bin/bash
xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "remove Control = Control_L"
xmodmap -e "keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L"
xmodmap -e "add Lock = Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "add Control = Control_L"
#End script
```

This is the .profile check in order to make the swap take place:

```bsh
if [ -f  "$HOME/.uxSwapCapsLock-and-Ctrl" ]; then
   .  $HOME/.uxSwapCapsLock-and-Ctrl
fi
```